# How to add URL ending to "w.location.href" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm not really bright at JavaScript, so how do I add to "w.location.href"?. I tried searching, but it's hard to formulate the right question too.

This is part of a bookmarklet for Chrome:

```
encodeURIComponent(w.location.href)
```

This will return the active URL in the broswer adress field, like http://www.domain.com. But how can I add to it so the ending will be like, "http://www.domain.com/?rcode=abc1234"?

I tried this:

```
encodeURIComponent(w.location.href + "?rcode=abc12345")
```

and

```
encodeURIComponent(w.location.href + ('?rcode=abc12345')
```

But nothing workes, OR, it droppes out the "=" in the added string.

--

Ok, I'm adding the EDITED "flipit" code here:

```
    javascript:void((function(d,w,p,s,r,t,l)%7Bt%3D(w.screenTop%7C%7Cw.screenY)%2B50%3Bl%3D(w.screenX%7C%7Cw.screenLeft)%2B(w.innerWidth%7C%7Cd.documentElement.offsetWidth%7C%7C0)/2-s/2%3Bw.__flipboard%3Dw.open(%27https://share.flipboard.com/bookmarklet/popout%3Fv%3D2%26title%3D%27%2BencodeURIComponent(d.title)%2B%27%26url%3D%27%2BencodeURIComponent(w.location.href + "?rcode=wlb535")%2B%27%26t%3D%27%2Bp,%27__flipboard_flipit%27,%27width%3D%27%2Bs%2B%27,height%3D%27%2Br%2B%27,top%3D%27%2Bt%2B%27,left%3D%27%2Bl%2B%27,location%3Dyes,resizable%3Dyes,status%3Dno,scrollbars%3Dno,personalbar%3Dno,toolbar%3Dno,menubar%3Dno%27)%3Bs%3Dd.createElement(%27script%27)%3Bs.setAttribute(%27type%27,%27text/javascript%27)%3Bs.setAttribute(%27src%27,%27https://d2jsycj2ly2vqh.cloudfront.net/bookmarklet/js/popout-helper.min.js%3Ft%3D%27%2Bp)%3Bd.body.appendChild(s)%3BsetTimeout(function()%7Bw.__flipboard.focus()%7D,50)%3B%7D)(document,window,(new Date().getTime()),535,565))
```

Comment: Shouldn't 'w' be 'window'?

Comment: What does it have to do with [google-chrome-extension] ?

Comment: w.location is used, I guess it will be the same.

Comment: @ExpertSystem, the extention is the Flipboard flipit button. I'm just adding the the encoded URL because I'm collecting my own affiliate links to a closed magazine. So, want to add the string at the end.

Comment: Ok, so in the 'encodeURIComponent(w.location.href)' part is what I'm trying to change.

Comment: Seing your updatyed answer `encodeURIComponent(w.location.href + "?rcode=abc12345")` seems to be what you are after. Why do you say it is not working for you ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem, I dont know why it doesnt work. Did you see my latest added "flipit" code in my inital post? Thats the Flipboard button code in the bookmarks bar. When I scroll that code to the 'encodeURIComponent(w.location.href) part, and add the code like you mention, to 'encodeURIComponent(w.location.href + "?rcode=abc1234"), there is now change in the function. The button captures the URL, but it doesnt add the last string after the +.

Comment: @Johnny: Are you sure (because it seems to work for me) ? Keep in mind that due to `encodeURIComponent()` you might see something like this instead: `%252F%253Fr%253Dabc12345`

Comment: @ExpertSystem, hm, okey. Thanks for helping out with this. Well, the way I test this is to use my modified flipip button to capture the page/productpage and flip it in to my closed Flipboard magazine. And from there I check the link it got, but what I see is just the original link, without "?rcode=abc1234" added at the end. But I'll try again tomorrow, and use another brower/computer.

Comment: @ExpertSystem. Hi. I still can't make this work, weird. I add the code, but the links are still the same...

Comment: @Johnny: Unfortunately, I don't have a flipboard account to check it. Could you post your edited bookmarklet code ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem Hi, sorry for this late follow up. Been having so much work. I added the edited flipit code in my org. post, the last codepart there. I still haven't got this to work...

Comment: @Johnny: Unfortunately, I can't test is, but could it be that `w.location.href` already contains query params ? Try adding `alert(w.location.href);` just before `w.__flipboard=w.open(...`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var url = window.location;
url = encodeURI(url + '?rcode=abc12345');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the location programmatically, use:

```
window.location.href += encodeURIComponent('?rcode=abc12345');
```

Comment: I couldn't make this work with this change...  see the code I added upove. But thanks :)